Notation for empirical measure (Dirac measure)
I am writing a paper in an area that I am relatively unfamiliar with, and I am after suggestions concerning notation.
Here the notion of empirical measure is introduced in the paper

In the notation, x^j are points in space, but the other two arguments at the foot of the Dirac symbol are functions in a Banach space. As you see, the occurrence of superscripts and subscripts at the foot of the Dyrac symbol is really awful (the formula has other typesetting oddities too, but I know how to solve them).
Have you come across papers or books in which the empirical measure is written differently, so that x^j and its relatives don't appear as a subscript?
Thank you

Without understanding the context, the use of the Dirac distribution symbol as the kernel of a point measure with functions is subtle.
Especially in a metric manifold the contravariant superscript notation for coordinates indicates, that pure linear coordinate functions are meant, that reduce the abstract
$$\delta(\mathbf x)  = \delta((x^1,\dots x^n))= \delta(x^1) \dots \delta(x^n)$$ to the product measure
